# How to remove / disable objectbox data browser service in release apk?

Tags: android, objectbox

In the release version of apk, I inspected the code, the below lines automatically added

```
<service android:name="io.objectbox.android.AndroidObjectBrowserService" android:exported="false" />
<receiver android:name="io.objectbox.android.AndroidObjectBrowserReceiver" android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="io.objectbox.action.KEEP_ALIVE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I once used db browser, but now I don't use Objectbox db browser in release apk, I also removed all dependencies, clean and rebuild the project, but this service still exists!

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your manifest to prevent those nodes from getting merged:

```
<receiver
    android:name="io.objectbox.android.AndroidObjectBrowserReceiver"
    tools:node="remove" />
<service
    android:name="io.objectbox.android.AndroidObjectBrowserService"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

You can also do this by opening your `AndroidManifest.xml`, switching to the **Merged Manifest** tab and right-click to remove those nodes (this adds the lines above to your manifest).

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge

We (ObjectBox) will remove those nodes from the `objectbox-android` artifact in a future update, so they will only get added if the `objectbox-android-objectbrowser` artifact is used. The above will then no longer be necessary.

Comment: Oh great, it's worked! finally I found a bug! Now I am a software engineer! ;)